# How to implement dynamic routing on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a project in Angular and we are separating business subjects by modules, for example we have two flows: hiring and activation, in hiring we have a component for credit card selection list and this component/page is being accessed by three different components(routes) and I'm not sure what is the best way to redirect the user when he chooses to go to the previous page. I made something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PreviousRouteService {
  private previousUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        pairwise()
      )
      .subscribe((events: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
        this.previousUrl = events[0].urlAfterRedirects;
        console.log('previous url', this.previousUrl);
      });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl(): string {
    return this.previousUrl;
  }

}
```

It's a service to get the previous route, but for example I have 4 pages, and the 3rd is the credit card selection list, when I get to the 4th and go back to the third I cannot go back to the second one because the previous would be the 4th. How can I fix this problem?